# Multiple XHR Request Progress Tracking

Tags: javascript

5 Requests is going on. If we take event.loaded it shows alternate values every time from random 5 progress events. How can we target each xhr requests?

```
var xhr = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    url = "/" + "?n=" + Math.random();
    xhr[i].open("POST", url, true);
    xhr[i].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr[i].upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);

    function progressHandler(event) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
      time = (end - start) / 1000;
      var duration = time;
      var bytes = event.loaded;
    }
  };
  xhr[i].send(UploadData);
```

Comment: It should concurrently without any Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using same handler for all 5 processes, you need individual handler for each. Then you can use shared scope to calculate overall progress:

```
var xhr = [];
var progress = [];


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    url = "/" + "?n=" + Math.random();
    xhr[i].open("POST", url, true);
    xhr[i].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr[i].upload.addEventListener("progress", createProgressHandler(start, i), false);
    xhr[i].send(UploadData);
    // Initialize progress:
    progress[i] = { bytes: 0 };
};

function createProgressHandler(start, i) {
    return function (event) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
      time = (end - start) / 1000;
      var duration = time;
      var bytes = event.loaded;

      progress[i].bytes = bytes;

      console.log('Event from upload #' + i + ', bytes loaded: ' + bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working, Now i can see each event data separately. How can i view selected request data? eg: i = 4 th file event data only?

Comment: I mean Display selected event only? to HTML

Comment: setup progress array, where you track progress separately for each item. In HTML update corresponding data, not sure if you are trying to show progress for each, or aggregate for all.

Comment: For each in separate HTML fields. Please give some direction to setup progress array.

Comment: Check updated answer, you can track anything you want there, and when those events fire, just update html.

Comment: Getting error like This >> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined  and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Your idea is working fine, Thanks. i made some changes var y = progress[0];
var x = progress[1];
_("009").innerHTML = "Even.loaded for first request  " + y + " bytes";
_("007").innerHTML = "Even.loaded for second request    " + x + " bytes";